# Listen to multiple RTSP Streams

Tags: windows-7, streaming, audio-streaming, rtsp, telecommunication

I plan on having multiple RTSP streaming servers on the same network:

rtsp://192.168.1.2
rtsp://192.168.1.3
rtsp://192.168.1.x

Is there any way I can listen to all of them in Windows 7 **at the same time**?  I don't need them to be synchronized into a file, but saving them to a file would be a plus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - since RTSP is a protocol with no defined standard codec - ensure that you have the correct codecs on your computer to decypher the stream when you have received it.

Onve you have managed to get your hands on the codecs, there are loads of freeware and open source RTSP capable media players - VLC Media player for instance

Regarding yoru wish to record the feeds in real time - again, a program like VLC has "save/convert" functionality which can capture a network feed from RTSP and save in a format to your PC.

Lastly, the aforementioned (sp?) software also supports opening multiple instances... as do many other media players which fulfill your criteria.

Ben

Comment: VLC Does do it, BUT ONLY if you run it as another instance.  I was looking for something that doesn't require multiple instances, but in fairness I guess I didn't specify that, so touché.